# Winforms in WPF - Searching for an event after instantiation but before rendering

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, windowsformshost

I'm trying to insert a winform control in WPF: 
    WFH:WindowsFormsHost Name="MyHost" 
The problem is that I can't access MyHost from the xaml.cs (It is somehow barried in the infrastructure). So I figured I can somehow throw an event, catch it in the code and then update MyHost.child to contain my winform control.
The problem is that I don't find any event which gets thrown after initialization but before rendering (I tried "initialized" but that seems too late).
Any ideas?

Thanks,
Li

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access WFH from the xaml.cs.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/WinF2WPF06192008213220PM/WinF2WPF.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788729.aspx

Hope this helps.

Regards!